# How does one translate this code to ActionScript 3.0?

Tags: php, actionscript-3, flash-cs4

I'm stumped with this code - it seems that every time I port some of the reserved words of this AS2 code (what it does is to send mail using both Flash and PHP), I'm getting errors

```
stop();

var senderLoad:LoadVars = new LoadVars();
var receiveLoad:LoadVars = new LoadVars();

sender.onRelease = function() {
    senderLoad.theName = theName.text;
    senderLoad.theEmail = theEmail.text;
    senderLoad.theMessage = theMessage.text;
    senderLoad.sendAndLoad("http://leebrimelow.com/mailExample/send.php",receiveLoad);
}

receiveLoad.onLoad = function() {
    if(this.sentOk) {
        _root.gotoAndStop("success");
    }
    else {
        _root.gotoAndStop("failed");
    }
}
 Any idea how?
```

Answer (score 2):

If you update LoadVars Object to As3 just use an UrlLoader Object like this code.

```
var mainLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://domain/mailExample/send.php");
var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
    variables.theName = theName.text;
    variables.theEmail = theEmail.text;
    variables.theMessage = theMessage.text;
    request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
    request.data = variables;
    mainloader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, handleComplete);
    mainLoader.load(request);




  private function handleComplete(event:Event):void {
        var loader:URLLoader = URLLoader(event.target);
   }
```

Comment: So, you're telling me that this is just part of the code I need to change - and leave the others as is?

Answer (score 0):

I'm n't expert in AS2 but I can help you with the syntax of AS3 you need for this code
try to see would help u 
it's the basic of the AS3 Concepts

[mouseevent as3](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/MouseEvent.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6)

[Function As3](http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/actionscript/as3-101-functions/)

and that's AS3 function syntax

```
bldg1_thumb1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, MyFunction);

function MyFunction (event:MouseEvent):void{
    gotoAndStop ("2");
}
```